# How to get more views on a question?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question and the first title wasn't that good, since then I researched some and edited the [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749785/windows-10-icon-dimensions-for-wpf-project-and-the-medium-tile-in-start-menu).

I really want to have a definitive answer to my questions and there should be plenty of people out there with it.

My question is: is it okay to repost the whole question to get fresh views? OR are there other ways to attract views?

Comment: Almost certain that this has been previously answered. But I don't have time to go dupe-hunting right now.

Comment: [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/288751)

Answer (score -8):

Okay, I got it: No repost.

From the posted answer in the comment:

1: I did this

2: I don't

3: Can't upvote own question

4: I don't use those

So in a sense my question was answered, so I'm going to mark it... But I found no solution just #1 what I did already from the beginning so in my case it will not help me get hits, thanks for the downvotes.